# Run gulp from laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel, gulp

I am attempting to run gulp from a Laravel controller, I have attempted to do `exec('pwd')` to give me my current directory which is `public/` so I need to move out one directory before running the gulp command. Now when i run `exec('cd ../ && gulp')` from within my controller nothing is happening. Yet if in the command line i type out `gulp` it compiles my SASS files for me.

Is there a way I can run gulp to compile my SASS files from within a laravel controller?

Comment: Try: `dd(shell_exec('cd ..; gulp'));` and see what you get back.

Comment: My response is null.

Comment: Okay. Now try the same, but use `exec` instead. It will output the exit code.

Comment: I then get an empty string.

Comment: Okay, try once more with `shell_exec`, but alter the command like so: `dd(shell_exec('cd ..; gulp 2>&1'));`

Comment: "env: node: No such file or directory\n"

Comment: Yet when i drop our pwd im in the root directory of my laravel application...

Comment: Try PHP's `getcwd()` function to determine where your current working directory is. Assuming you are in the Controller directory, then this is your cwd: `App\Http\Controllers`. So you need to go three steps back and try it. `../../../`

Comment: I am in a controller in App\Http\Controllers but, I get /Websites/laravel/public as a result of getcwd()

Comment: If i do like dd(shell_exec('cd ../; composer --version')); it gives me the composer version but it wont let me do the gulp commands.

Comment: Then you must make sure that `gulp` is in your environment variable. Try dumping `$_SERVER`.

Comment: Theres nothing in $_SERVER relating to gulp, how can i add it to my environment variables?

Comment: I'm assuming you installed `gulp` globally. Confirm by opening your terminal and doing `which gulp`. Copy the output from that and use the whole path instead of using `cd ..; gulp` only. Example: `cd ..; /usr/local/bin/gulp`. This is the only thing left in my mind to try.

Comment: which gulp returns nothing. I have installed gulp globally.

Comment: If you are using an unix based OS, then the command should definitely return something if you installed it globally. Does running `gulp` by itself via Terminal work for your project?

Comment: In my project (mac OS) when i run gulp it compiles my SASS files

Comment: Reinstalled I now get, /usr/local/bin/gulp

Comment: dd(shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/gulp 2>&1')); also gives me the env: node: No such file or directory.

Comment: Alright, try your original `cd .. & '/usr/local/bin/gulp 2>&1`

Comment: I did set_env() and put in the $PATH var and it worked :)